# get data to listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, datatable

I have made a DataTable in code behind, in VB.NET. I need to call it to from my .ASPX page and show this as a ListView.

My code behind is:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

' columns in the DataTable.
table.Columns.Add("Monday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
table.Columns.Add("Tuesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
table.Columns.Add("Wednesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
table.Columns.Add("Thursday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
table.Columns.Add("Friday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
'  rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
table.Rows.Add(1, 2005, 2000, 4000, 34)
table.Rows.Add(2, 3024, 2343, 2342, 12)
table.Rows.Add(3, 2320, 9890, 1278, 2)
table.Rows.Add(4, 3420, 1234, 4321, 89)
table.Rows.Add(5, 3240, 6600, 1100, 56)
table.Rows.Add(6, 4320, 1100, 3243, 23)
table.Rows.Add(7, 4540, 7645, 4324, 56)
```

I want to only show Monday and Tuesday on the .ASPX page. How will i do this? At the moment I have this:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="Listview1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                    monday
                </th>
                <th>
                    tuesday
                </th>
                <th>
                    wednesday
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="holder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <!--some code goes here am guessing-->
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

this in the aspx code behind?

```
Property readonly Data() As DataTable



End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ASPX the following:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="table" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        monday
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        tuesday
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmon" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("monday") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltues" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("tuesday") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

And in your vb.net the following:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim table As New DataTable

    ' columns in the DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add("Monday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Tuesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Wednesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Thursday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Friday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    '  rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
    table.Rows.Add(1, 2005, 2000, 4000, 34)
    table.Rows.Add(2, 3024, 2343, 2342, 12)
    table.Rows.Add(3, 2320, 9890, 1278, 2)
    table.Rows.Add(4, 3420, 1234, 4321, 89)
    table.Rows.Add(5, 3240, 6600, 1100, 56)
    table.Rows.Add(6, 4320, 1100, 3243, 23)
    table.Rows.Add(7, 4540, 7645, 4324, 56)

    Me.table.DataSource = table
    Me.table.DataBind()
End Sub
```

In an ASCX, put this code in a method, and call it in the Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    BindData()
End Sub

Private Sub BindData()
    Dim table As New DataTable

    ' columns in the DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add("Monday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Tuesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Wednesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Thursday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Friday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    '  rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
    table.Rows.Add(1, 2005, 2000, 4000, 34)
    table.Rows.Add(2, 3024, 2343, 2342, 12)
    table.Rows.Add(3, 2320, 9890, 1278, 2)
    table.Rows.Add(4, 3420, 1234, 4321, 89)
    table.Rows.Add(5, 3240, 6600, 1100, 56)
    table.Rows.Add(6, 4320, 1100, 3243, 23)
    table.Rows.Add(7, 4540, 7645, 4324, 56)

    Me.table.DataSource = table
    Me.table.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Place my code in your page. I changed the Ids, and I tested my code on my testing website, and it works.

Comment: Try creating a new website, adding a new default page, and pasting my .ASPX and .ASPX.VB respectively. You should get the hang of it quite easily.

Comment: Ideally put the code in my Page_Load, in a method named something like LoadData(), and call it within your ASCX control, in the Page_Load method.

Comment: another error, on datasource.   'datasouce'is not a member of 'system.data.datatable'

Comment: From what I understand you are trying to use DataSource, on the DataTable. DataSource is a member of a DataGrid, GridView, ListView etc... I think you might have altered the code - check out my answer and use it as a guide.